# Vlookup in awk: how to list anything occuring in file2 but not in file1 at the end of output?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have two files, file 1:

```
1    800     800     0.51
2    801     801     0.01
3    802     802     0.01
4    803     803     0.23
```

and file 2:

```
1    800     800     0.55
2    801     801     0.09
3    802     802     0.88
4    804     804     0.24
```

I have an awk script that looks in the second file for values that match the first three columns of the first file.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3];next} {if (($1,$2,$3) in a) {print $4} else {print "not found"}}' f1 f2
0.55
0.09
0.88
not found
```

Is there a way to make it such that any rows occurring in file 2 that are not in file 1 are still added at the end of the output, after the matches, such as this:

```
0.55
0.09
0.88
not found
4    804     804     0.24
```

That way, when I paste the two files back together, they will look something like this:

```
1 800 800 0.51 0.55
2 801 801 0.01 0.09
3 802 802 0.01 0.88
4 803 803 0.23 not found
4 804 804 not found 0.04
```

Or is there any other more elegant solution with completely different syntax?

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk '{k=$1FS$2FS$3}NR==FNR{a[k]=$4;next}
      k in a{print $4;next}{print "not found";print}' f1 f2
```

The above one-liner will give you:

```
0.55
0.09
0.88
not found
4 804 804 0.24
```

Comment: I don't really follow the code. Could you tell me, is there a way to make it output the last line as:


    4 804 804 notfound 0.24

This way the 0.24 will be in the 5th column, where the rest of the data from file 2 will be when this output is pasted back with file 1, and notfound in column 4 will indicate that this location does not exist in file 1

I also changed "not found" to "notfound", otherwise the past command thinks this is two columns, not 1.

Comment: to clarify, when I paste it back, I want it to look like the last block of code in my question.

Comment: also when there are two rows in file 2 that are not in file 1, it prints 
"not found" between each row...ALSO, they are printed in the same order that they appear in file2, when i need to print them in the same order as file 1...(e.g. if the order in file 2 is reversed, it will still print the same result) any ideas?